# How to convert a numeric string to a float in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to migrate a program from Java to Python.
In this application I will read a text file and will process the data based on the record type. 
Each of this record stores an amount value as a 12 char i.e. 22.10 will be stored as 000000002210.

In Java I would do the following to convert 000000002210 to 22.10

```
String s = "000000002210";
byte[] b = s.getBytes();
System.out.println(" AMT : " + new BigInteger(b).floatValue());
```

Can anyone help me doing the same using Python.

Please note, I am using Python2.7 in Windows 7.

Comment: so in your data is allways verified that the last 2 digits of a 12 chars string are the decimals, or the decimals can be more?

Comment: @Lupanoide Yes, the last 2 digit will be the decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your numeric string to float and then use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting) and [pyformat](https://pyformat.info/)

```
s='00002210'
d = format(float(s)/100,'.02f')
print(d)
```

output:

```
22.10
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there will always be **two** decimal places, you can convert the `string` to an `int` and then divide by `100`. Python will automatically convert the `int` to type `float`.

So you could just do:

```
s = "000000002210"
print(int(s) / 100)
```

which will output:

```
22.1
```